# Python: TypeError: Required argument 'sequence' (pos 1) not found on outputing datetime tuple

Tags: python-3.x

On Output `print(time.struct_time())` for python data and time function.

`TypeError: Required argument 'sequence' (pos 1) not found`

I just want to access any particular tuple item of the

```py
time.localtime()
```

output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `time.struct_time` is a class and not an function. Several functions in the time module such as `gmtime()`, `asctime()` etc. either take time.struct_time object as an argument or return it.In your case `time.localtime()` function takes the number of seconds passed since epoch as an argument and returns struct_time in local time.If no argument or `None` is passed to `localtime()`, the value returned by `time()` is used.

The attribute in time.struct_time are

```
index   Attribute    Values
0       tm_year      0000, ...., 2018, ..., 9999
1       tm_mon       1, 2 , ..., 12
2       tm_mday      1, 2, ..., 31
3       tm_hour      0, 1, ..., 23
4       tm_min       0, 1, ..., 59
5       tm_sec       0, 1, ..., 61
6       tm_wday      0 , 1, ..., 6; Monday is 0
7       tm_yday      1, 2, ..., 366
8       tm_isdst     0, 1 or -1
```

The values (elements) of the `time.struct_time` object are accessible using both indices and attributes.

Example for getting the attributes from the `time.struct_time` object
    import time

```
result = time.localtime()
print("result:", result)
print("\nyear:", result.tm_year)
print("tm_hour:", result.tm_hour)
```

You can also use index to access the attributs

```
import time

result = time.localtime()
print("result:", result)
print("\nyear:", result[0])
print("tm_hour:", result[3])
```

The both will result the same output

```
Output:
result: time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=21, tm_min=57, tm_sec=29, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=165, tm_isdst=0)

year: 2020
tm_hour: 21
```